# Smarter smart bracket matching

Tags: balanced-parentheses

It's kind of weird how un-ergonomically placed the parenthesis keys are. 
 I'd like a function that smartly brackets my stuff for me based on context:

- If the mark is active, the region should be enclosed by ()
- If the mark is not active and the cursor is in the middle of a symbol, it should enclose the region between the cursor and the next whitespace: `foo|bar bla -> foo(|bar) bla`.
- Consecutive calls should result in cycling the bracket type, i.e. `(x) -> [x] -> {x} -> ('x') -> ("x") -> ...`

This would be awesome. Does there exist a package/function that does something similar already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item one is provided by [simple-paren](http://github.com/andreas-roehler/simple-paren)

The first step of the last request for the moment is realized via keys:

`(global-set-key [(super \()] 'simple-paren-parentize)`

`(global-set-key [(super \[)] 'simple-paren-bracket)`

etc.

Item two: push mark at point, forward-word followed by one of the commands above - done.

WRT cycling you may consider a feature request.